# OpenCV 4 no Visual Studio 2018

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

Estou tentando utilizar a biblioteca OpenCV no Visual Studio, porém obtenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: não é possível abrir o arquivo
> 'opencv_calib3d400.lib'

A lib encontra-se no local C:\opencv4\build\lib\Release e não estou utilizando-a.

Segue o print:

[image: Print]

Segue a simples implementação sem erro de sintaxe:

## OpenCV4.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>


int main()
{
    cv::String path = "C:/opencv4/OpenCV4VS2018/OpenCV4VS2018/xicara.jpg";
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread(path);
    cv::imshow("test", src);
    cv::waitKey(10000);
    return 0;
    // std::cout << "De quem é esse Jegue?!\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31906940/8353154

Comment: Lembre-se de adicionar as dependências (libraries e includes) de Debug e de Release. Se for a do debug, normalmente o arquivo termina com a letra d.

Comment: Ao entrar na pasta, vi que não haviam libs, então colei os arquivos lá. Agora o Visual Studio mudou a mensagem informando que os arquivos são para 32 bits e não para 64 bits.

Comment: Erro LNK1112 tipo de módulo de máquina 'x86' conflita com tipo de máquina alvo 'x64' OpenCV4VS2018 C:\opencv4\OpenCV4VS2018\OpenCV4VS2018\opencv_highgui400.lib(opencv_highgui400.dll) 1